# Close shared library when closing lua state

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

I'm using a custom shared library from lua. To load this library I have the required by Lua function `luaopen_mylib`. However this library needs to free resources and other thing when its being unloaded; so I'm wondering, does Lua calls some function when closing a shared library (`luaclose_*` or similar).

If not, any suggestions of how to do that?, note that the lua code isn't actually aware that it is being closed before I call `lua_close(luaState)`, only the host program knows about it.

The shared library is multithreaded, if that needs special handling.

Comment: Define a `__gc` metamethod.

Comment: where should I define that metamethod?, as a field in the metatable of the table returned by the library?

Comment: This is not easy task especialy if you work weith multithreaded application. Checkout my attempt to do this. https://github.com/moteus/lua-luq/blob/master/src/luq_library_lock.c

Comment: usage https://github.com/moteus/lua-luq/blob/5038090ad1a0c1c1ce2a001093f33cb196bcddbb/src/luq.c#L255-L260

Comment: @JavierMr - `Any_Global_Variable = setmetatable({}, {__gc = function() ... end})`

Comment: This works only for single threaded.  if you load library from several thread os unload library only all thread close they lua states

Comment: In your `luaopen_xyz()` function: Increment a global counter variable (protected by a mutex), create a userdata and store it in the registry. In the userdata's `__gc` metamethod (which will be called during `lua_close()`) decrement the global counter variable (again protected by the mutex) and run your cleanup function if the global counter has reached zero.